# Kafka streams: Combining KStreams and Processor API?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream implemented using the high-level Kafka Streams `KStream` API and would like to attach *two* consecutive processors to this stream.

The `KStream` API provides a [process](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#process(org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorSupplier,%20java.lang.String...)) method, however that method does not return anything so I assume it mutates the topology.

After the first processor I would like to attach a second one however and it's not entirely clear to me which object I can add the downstream processor to.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you consider using `transform()` instead of `process()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to filter keys and value with a Processor using Kafka Stream DSL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40814437/how-to-filter-keys-and-value-with-a-processor-using-kafka-stream-dsl)