# How to filter keys and value with a Processor using Kafka Stream DSL

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a Processor that interact with a StateStore to filter and do complex logic on the messages. In the `process(key,value)` method I use `context.forward(key,value)` to send the keys and values that I need. For debugging purposes I also print those.

I have a KStream `mergedStream` that results from a join of two other streams. I want to apply the processor to the records of that stream. I achieve this with : `mergedStream.process(myprocessor,"stateStoreName")`

When I start this program, I can see the proper values to be printed to my console. However if I send  the mergedStream to a topic using `mergedStream.to("topic")` the values on the topic are not the one I have forwarded in the processor, but the original ones.

I use kafka-streams 0.10.1.0.

What is the best way to get the values I have forwarded in the processor to another stream ?

Is it possible to mix the [Processor API](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#processor-api) with the streams created by the [KStream DSL](http://docs.confluent.io/3.0.0/streams/developer-guide.html#streams-developer-guide-dsl)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Short:**

To solve your problem you can use `transform(...)` instead of `process(...)` which gives you access to Processor API within DSL, too.

**Long**:

If you use `process(...)` you apply a processor to a stream -- however, this is a "terminating" (or sink) operation (its return type is `void`), i.e., it does not return any result (here "sink" does only mean that the operator has no successor -- it does not imply that any result is written somewhere!)

Furthermore, if you call `mergedStream.process(...)` and `mergedStream.to(...)` you basically branch-and-duplicate your stream and send one copy to each downstream operator (ie, one copy to `process` and one copy to `to`.

Mixing DSL and Processor API is absolutely possible (you did it already ;)). However, using `process(...)` you cannot consumer data you `forward(...)` within DSL -- if you want to consume Processor API result, you can use `transform(...)` instead of `process(...)`.

Comment: How would you use DSL if in your Processor API code you forward to more than one topic(outputTopic1, outputTopic2)? 
Could you create `val stream1 = builder.stream(outputTopic)` and `val stream2 = builder.stream(outputTopic2)` and build from there?

Comment: If you write to two different topics in via Processor API, yes, you can read each topic back as KStream as you describe. Note, that if you call `context.forward()` you don't write to any topic but forward to a named downstream processor. Not sure what you want to achieve. Maybe it's worth to ask a separate question :)

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that my forwards go to sinks to two different topics (that will be consumed by other applications too). Implications on new subtopologies come in, so I'll make a question though, since I think it's relevant. Thanks!

Comment: Will there be a way to continue with the DSL after using `.process()`? It could be so useful, I understand it can be challenging specially when it's regarding the unknown next node from the processor, but maybe there's a way to circumvent that!

Comment: It will not be possible. `process()` is designed to be a terminal operation. If you want to continue you can use `transform()` (or `flatTransfrom()`, `transformValues()`, or `flatTransformValue()`) -- note that the only difference between `transform()` and `process()` is terminal vs non-terminal. Ie, by picking `process()` you explicitly decide to  not continue! If you want to continue, pick `transform()`.